# Inject method call to all field setters marked with attribute using Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I have class with the method:

```
class NetworkObject {

  protected void LocalNetworkVariableChange(object value) {
    // Do some stuff
  }

}
```

I also have Mono.Cecil setup so that it injects a method call to this method in properties marked with a [NetworkVariable] attribute:

```
class Foo : NetworkObject {

  public String Data {
  get {
    return ...
  }
  set {
    // existing code here
    ...  

    // Injected call
    this.LocalNetworkVariableChange(value);
  }

}
```

This works fine using this code:

```
var propertySetMethod = property.SetMethod;
ILProcessor processor = propertySetMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();
var lastInstruction = propertySetMethod.Body.Instructions.Last();
var valueOperand = (FieldDefinition)propertySetMethod.Body.Instructions
  .First(i => i.OpCode == OpCodes.Stfld)
  .Operand;

var onLocalChangeMethod = assembly.MainModule
  .Types.Single(td => td.FullName == typeof(NetworkObject).FullName)
  .Methods.Single(md => md.Name == "LocalNetworkVariableChange")
  .Resolve();

var newInstructions = new List<Instruction> {
  // Load this on the evaluation step
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0),

  // Load to the stack the index of network variable
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, index),

  // Loads the local variable at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc_0),

  // Finds the value of a field in the object whose reference is currently on the evaluation stack.
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldfld, valueOperand),

  // Call the method
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Callvirt, onLocalChangeMethod),

  // Insert Nop before return
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Nop)
};

foreach (var newInstruction in newInstructions) {
  processor.InsertBefore(lastInstruction, newInstruction);
}
```

So whenever the setter is called, my method is called after.
Now I need the same for *fields*, additionally to the properties.

But what can I do? Any idea?
Can I convert the field to property and how?

Comment: How it supposed to work for fields? Props are easy as you only inject the code into the property itself (set method). For fields you would need to find all the places where the property is used and add the call after and do some bookkeeping with the code that goes after. Probably doable but a lot of work

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple: Every setter to the field is prolonged with a call to the method. I loop over all instructions of all members of all classes of all assemblies and search for `OpCodes.StdFld` instructions that set the field. Than right after the setter I inject the following calls.

```
var injections = new List<Instruction> {
  // Load this on the evaluation step
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0),

  // Load to the stack the index of network variable
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, index),

  // Load this on the evaluation step to be able to fetch field value next
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0),

  // Load the field value again
  Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldfld, (FieldReference)instruction.Operand),
};

if (operand.FieldType.IsValueType) {
  // Box the value because the argument is an object
  injections.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Box, operand.FieldType));
}

// Call the method
injections.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, onLocalChangeMethod));
```

The boxing here is one part that I forgot in my initial question.